Font shape and size substitution error when using dingbat in the same document as esvect
There are two errors which show up with the following MWE. How can I circumvent these?

Font shape `U/esvect/m/n' in size <7.5> not available

Size substitutions with differences.


Thank you
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect,stix}
\begin{document}
Try typing both $\parallelogram$ and $\vv{a}$
\end{document}


You should read the whole message not only some parts of them. As the start of the message: “LaTeX Font Warning” shows: These are not errors but warnings. And as the second part of the first message: “size <7> substituted” explains, the result is that U/esvect/m/n is used in 7pt instead of 7.5pt. Can you show a case, where this is really relevant? If not: Ignore the warning.

@cabohah Interesting, I was under the impression that these warnings were - as a blanket rule - to be gotten rid of. Thank you for the insight as to how you approach these messages.

@Jasper it depends on what the warning says ;).

stix uses
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{7.5}{6}

But font U/esvect/m/n is not available in size 7.5pt. Uesvect.fd defines only some sizes:
\DeclareFontShape{U}{esvect}{m}{n}{%
      <5><6><7><8><9><10>gen*vect%
      <10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>vect10%
      }{}

So it is automatically substituted by 7pt, as shown in the complete messages:
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/esvect/m/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.5pt have occurred.

If you just want to get rid of the warning message you can change the 7.5, e.g., by 7:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect,stix}
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{7}{6}
\begin{document}
Try typing both $\parallelogram$ and $\vv{a}$
\end{document}

This would select a little bit smaller font for script-size than stix would do.
You can alternatively use a larger font size:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect,stix}
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{8}{6}
\begin{document}
Try typing both $\parallelogram$ and $\vv{a}$
\end{document}

One more alternative would be to add a silent scale rule for 7.5pt to the esvect declaration:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect,stix}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{esvect}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{esvect}{m}{n}{%
  <5><6><7><8><9><10>gen*vect
  <7.5>s*[1.071] vect7
  <10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>vect10
}{}

\begin{document}
Try typing both $\parallelogram$ and $\vv{a}$
\end{document}

See section “4.3 Font file loading information” in “LaTeX 2ε font selection” aka fntguide.pdf for more information about the definition.
Other alternative (which I would use, but this is just an opinion): Ignore the warning.
